# Array of select field with same name and different id.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have an array of select fields all having the same list of option value. What i am trying to get is, if a value is selected in any of the field, it should not show on the other. Below is an example code. For example, if I am having four select fields, if I select 'a' on first field, the value "a" should not appear on the next select field. Same with other values of "b", "c" and "d".
I am trying to use java script for the same. I am in learning phase. help will be really appreciated. Thanks

```
<select name='list' id='list_1'>
    <option value='a'>a</option>
    <option value='b'>b</option>
    <option value='c'>c</option>
    <option value='d'>d</option>
</select>
<select name='list' id='list_2'>
<option value='b'>b</option>
<option value='c'>c</option>
<option value='d'>d</option>

</select>
<select name='list' id='list_3'>
<option value='c'>c</option>
<option value='d'>d</option>
</select>
<select name='list' id='list_4'>
<option value='d'>d</option>
</select>
```

Comment: change `name` attribute values to `List[1],list[2],list[2]`, and it will be always possible to distinguish them. OR `List[list_1],list[list_2],list[list_3]`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrsC6/8/ - It doesn't quite work, but you get the idea

Comment: What if the user chooses a value from the last select first?

Comment: @nnnnnn hes vice versa is posiible

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to destroy the data, you need to hide the options.
That's tricky because you have multiple state to combine.

you can make several IF comparisons, hard-code a table of combos for each group and options (yuck), or use a mountain of JS to solve this, but i think that CSS is better.

A simple way to accomplish this is to use CSS; multiple classes on a single element that translate your many states into rules that can be applied instantly and generically (without hard-coding ids or names).

```
<select name='list' id='list_1'>
    <option value='a'>a</option>        <option value='b'>b</option>
    <option value='c'>c</option>        <option value='d'>d</option>
</select>
<select name='list' id='list_2'>
    <option value='a'>a</option>        <option value='b'>b</option>
    <option value='c'>c</option>        <option value='d'>d</option>
</select>
<select name='list' id='list_3'>
    <option value='a'>a</option>        <option value='b'>b</option>
    <option value='c'>c</option>        <option value='d'>d</option>
</select>
<select name='list' id='list_4'>
    <option value='a'>a</option>        <option value='b'>b</option>
    <option value='c'>c</option>        <option value='d'>d</option>
</select>


<script src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>  
<script>

var combos=[], // store the css we need to define hide/show rules
    classes= new Array($("select").length); //a place to store many states

$("select").each(function(i,e){ // for every drop down,      
   $(this).change(function(){ // when it changes:
    classes[i]=this.value; // update array with changed value in right slot
    document.body.className=classes.join(" "); // update body class with array
   });

});

$("select option[value]").each(function(n, a){ // make css to hide each option if body has the same class:
  combos.push( "body."+a.value+" option[value='"+a.value+"'] ");
});

//append the dynamic CSS to the head:  
$("head").append("<style> "+combos+"{ display: none; }</style>");  

</script>
```

online demo: http://pagedemos.com/pe2uf5vkx9vh/

if you want to restrict this functionality to certain drop downs, give them a class like `<select class=hider` and change `$("select` to `$("select.hider` in the code above.

if you have values with spaces, you'll need fancier CSS selectors than class, like `data-state="|a b|hello world|honda crv|"` attribs that you can delimit and hit with partial attribute selectors (`body[data-state*='|hello world|']...`), but the same pattern *can* work with many and more complex states.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code that i have written .. Hope should help

```
<select>
  <option value="0"> </option>
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="0"> </option>
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="0"> </option>
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
</select>

$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
   $(this).find('option:selected').addClass('keepit');
   $('option[value="' + this.value + '"]:not( .keepit)').remove();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/av46dbo1/

Comment: i like that simplicity, but can you hide them instead of removing them? (user change minds, and disabled users need the KB, which fires change() on every option as they scroll down...) i couldn't find a simple way to do that...

Comment: Thanks @dandavis came back to stackoverflow after years but  its still has the same problem people getting the solution but not bothering to accept answer. But i not leaving this time and i appreciate people like you who actually are there to help other... i love this thing about programmers

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ktbanvy/2/)

```
 $(function(){
      $('#list_1').change(function(){
      var valueToRemove=$(this).val();

      $('select').not('#list_1').each(function(){
      var currentId=$(this).prop('id');
      $("#"+currentId+" option[value="+valueToRemove+"]").remove();
      })
    })
    })
```

Comment: @dandavis as these are static dropdowns, so, repopulate would be tricky